# Kibana 4 timestamp

Tags: kibana-4

When trying to do the simplest graph of the amount of logs in kibana4 I get this (screenshot of my kibana window): [image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/rvs6n.png] (clickable)

To be more clear: the x-axis gives me _all, and then some way down @timestamp which, if I hover over it, gives me the correct timestamp that I actually need

The timestamps won't appear properly, whatever I do.
I also tried modifying the X-axis by doing the subaggregation->terms->@timestamp/time/time.raw. These all didn't work for me.

Any help would be greatly appreciated, since I am new to Kibana4

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get a time series chart in kibana 4, your X axis needs to be a Date Histogram on your `@timestamp` field.